# How to Add Value to Log Before Resetting (CoreData & Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, logging

**Background info:** I have a simple tally counter/habit-tracking app that populates a tableview with custom cells - the counters. Tapping on a cell brings up a detailed view of a specific counter that has the name, value, and the time period for that counter (daily/weekly/monthly/yearly/total). I have also stored in CoreData the startDate and endDate for each counter, so each counter resets after a certain time.

**What I would like to do:** Each time a counter resets (e.g. after a day or a week), I would like its current total value to be added to a log (preferably some sort of array) specific to that counter. This will then populate another tableview so that, after a few weeks, I can look back and see the previous weekly totals and compare it to the current week.

**My data structure:**

Entity: Counter

Attributes: Value (Int), startDate(NSDate), endDate(NSDate), timePeriod(Int) (Note: For timePeriod, each integer from 0 to 4 represents daily/weekly/monthly/yearly/no reset.)

**My question: How can I implement this? Do I create another entity with a date and value attribute that is created each time a counter resets? I'm having trouble visualizing how to do this with CoreData.**

P.S. I don't think using tableview and fetch requests is what I'm looking for.

Thanks so much for your help, and ask me if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to not "reset" the counter but create a new one. You can then easily display the past counters. That would avoid creating a new entity.

To make it even simpler to distinguish them from active counters you could add a flag like `active` or `archived`. You could use that flag for a convenient predicate in your fetched results controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one clarification question though: since people will have multiple counters, how to I query to only return a specific counter's results? I can't do it by identical name because there may be multiple counters with the same name, and because the user can edit the counter name at any time so it may change.

Comment: Just use another attribute to make that distinction. E.g., a counter `type` that you define or let the user define, regardless of the name.